# Наследование шаблона

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function inherit_A(Child, Parent) {
        var F = function () {};
        F.prototype = Parent.prototype;

        Child.prototype = new F();
        Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
        Child.super = Parent.prototype;
    }

    function Par(name) {
        this.name = name || 'kill'
    }
    Par.prototype.say = function () {
        return this.name
    }

    function Chi() {}
    inherit_A(Chi, Par)

    obj = new Chi()
    alert(obj.say()) //underfined
</script>
```

Comment: Интересует именно этот шаблон,когда наследуются колько свойста в прототипе

Comment: На CoffeeScript посмотрите, между делом. Помогает не писать лишний бойлерплейт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function inherit_A(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function () { };
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;

    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
    Child.prototype.super = Parent.prototype;
    // parent prototype better store in child prototype

    Child.prototype.$super = function() {
        // method to call parent constructor
        Parent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

function Par(name){
    this.name=name||'kill'
}

Par.prototype.say = function() {
  return this.name;
}

function Chi( name ){

   this.$super( name );
   // or
   this.$super.apply(this, arguments);
   // apply all arguments to parent constructor
}

inherit_A(Chi, Par);

var c1 = new Chi();
var c2 = new Chi('test');

console.log( c1.say() ); // -> kill
console.log( c2.say() ); // -> test
```

---

[JavaScript apply](http://javascript.ru/Function/apply)

Comment: Эти строки копируют свойства? Без них наследоваться будут только свойства в прототипах?

    this.$super( name );
    // or
    this.$super.apply(this, arguments);

Comment: Во первых это 2 разных варианта.

Оба лишь вызывают родительский конструктор, соответственно ничего они не копируют, копирует `inherit_A`

Вообще вам бы мат-часть сначала подучить...

Comment: по чем ты сделал вывод о уровне моих знаний в математике?

Comment: LOL, [Учи матчасть](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)