# Как лучше всего описать наследование в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как лучше всего сделать наследование в JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего использовать способ с подставным конструктором:

```
function inherit (object, parent) {
    function F(){}; // Подставной конструктор
    F.prototype = parent.prototype; // Подсовываем прототип реального конструктора
    object.prototype = new F(); // Теперь реальный конструктор не будет выполнен
    return object; // Можно и не возвращать
};
```

функция `__extends` из CoffeScript:

```
function(child, parent) { 
    for (var key in parent) { 
        if (parent.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
            child[key] = parent[key]; 
    } 
    function ctor() { 
        this.constructor = child; 
    } 
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
    child.prototype = new ctor(); 
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype; 
    return child; 
};
```

- [Клонирование свойств прототипа родителя в прототип ребенка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/129804/)
- [Наследование шаблона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/106197/)
- [Основы и заблуждения насчет JavaScript](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120193/)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь есть много выходов, лучший, имхо - использование прототипа. Подробнее **[смотрите здесь](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance#nasledovanie-na-klassah-funkciya-extend)**.

---

В javascript базовое наследование основано не на классах. То есть, нет такого, что классы наследуют друг от друга, а объект класса-потомка получает общие свойства.

Вместо этого объекты наследуют от объектов без всяких классов. Наследование на классах можно построить(эмулировать), опираясь на базовое наследование javascript.

Comment: ну там по разному используется прототип.
Вот это нормальный вариант

    function SomeClass(_Arg1, _Arg2)
    {
       Parent1.call(this, Arg1);
       Parent2.call(this, Arg2);

       // далее, собственные методы и свойства SomeClass
    }
Мне лично больше нравится через замыкание делать

Comment: "Вот это нормальный вариант"

Ни одна известная мне JS среда, с т.з. производительности  не согласна с твоим утверждением. ( причем, порой, речь об очень серьезных цифрах )

Comment: "Вот это нормальный вариант" это был вопрос. Ну это мне не очень нравится. Я делаю через замыкание или фабрику объектов, как еще ее называют

Answer (score -2):

prototype - свойство функции-конструктора, указывающее на объект, на основе которого она делает новые объекты. Не в том смысле, что содержит предка функции-конструктора, а в том, что содержит предка для всех объектов, которые эта функция создаст.

> constructor - свойство объекта, указывающее на функцию, которой он сделан.
>   TwoDShape.prototype = new Shape();

ставит в качестве объекта-основы объект-результат работы функции Shape, включающий в том числе и свойство constructor, которое указывает что объект сделала функция Shape.

new TwoDShape()
создаст объект, в свойстве constructor которого будет указано что он создан функцией Shape. Чтобы было правильно указано, что он сделан функцией TwoDShape, делают

> TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = TwoDShape;

Вообще, сам механизм прототипного наследования реализовани через скрытое свойство **proto**, это в нем хранится ссылка на объект-прототип и это цепочку этих объектов javascript проходит при поиске свойств и методов. А constructor просто указывает функцию, которой был создан объект, и вроде ничего больше. Если его менять, то будет указывать правильную, если нет - то функцию, создавшую самый верхний объект в цепочке прототипов.